# Criteria query com expressão contains no campo de uma entidade ManyToOne

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-2, criteria

Considerando as duas entidades abaixo:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="cliente")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Cliente {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_cliente", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $nome;
    // getters, setters, etc...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="pedido")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Pedido {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_pedido", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cliente")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_cliente", referencedColumnName="id_cliente")
     */
    private $cliente;
    // getters, setters, etc...
}
```

É possível fazer a seguinte busca ?

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->contains('cliente.nome', 'Felippe'));
$pedidos = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Admin\Models\Pedido')
        ->matching($criteria);
```

O seguinte erro está sendo retornado:

> Unrecognized field: cliente.nome

Desenvolvi um pacote de classes utilitárias para lidar com as buscas do plugin jQuery DataTables, e para isto criei um GenericDAO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você precisa de uma coleção de pedidos cujo nome do cliente que efetuou os pedidos é "Felippe", correto?

Eu faria isso usando uma DQL, mesmo:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Repositories; // ou outro namespace à sua escolha

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PedidoRepository extends EntityRepository

public function findByClienteNome($nome)
{
    return $this
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p
            FROM Admin\Models\Pedido p
            JOIN p.cliente c
            WHERE c.name = :name')
        ->setParameter('name', $nome)
        ->getResult();
}
```

Daí o uso ficaria assim:

```
$pedidos = $this
    ->getEntityManager()
    ->getRepository('Admin\Models\Pedido')
    ->findByClienteNome('Felippe');
```

A propósito, você precisa discriminar na sua model de `Pedido` qual é o repositório de objetos do tipo `Pedido`:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Models;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Admin\Models\PedidoRepository")
 */
class Pedido
{
    // etc...
}
```